# Dojo dialog block events

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, dialog

Is there any properite or function that I could use on my Dojo dialog to block everything that is behind the dialog. Block all events ....

I've searched the documentaion but haven't found anything useful.

Let's say when I am scrolling in the dialog I don't want the whole page to be scrolled...

Comment: You can set add a style property to your body tag when your dialog appears, like "overflow:hide".

Comment: Uhm, `dijit/Dialog` seems to work fine for me, I can't click on anything behind the dialog when it is up... Or is it just the scrolling which is a problem?

Comment: It just the scrolling...

Comment: I know it's jquery but maybe you can change it to javascript : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887332/disable-browser-scrolling-while-jquery-ui-modal-dialog-is-open