# Change scrolling from whole page to single div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

On my webpage when I click an element, modal window (div with fixed position) shows up. Problem is, that when I am scrolling using mouse scroll (or using finger on my phone/tablet), whole page is scrolling, and I want scrolling to be applied to content of the div (it has scroll bar) and stop scrolling the page. When the div is hidden, I want scorlling to switch back to whole page. Is it possible?
I tried disabling scroll of body when I show div (jQuery):

```
$("body").css({"overflow", "hidden"})
```

but the only effect I get is that page scrollbar is being hidded, but still mouse scroll scrolls the whole page (behind the div I want to scroll).

Comment: Look here I think it's the same problem as yours http://stackoverflow.com/q/4887332/3374815

Comment: Live link of the page where you are facing this issue? or at least add HTML n CSS related to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into event bubbling so the parent scroll (body) isn't triggered when you try to scroll the div

https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/