# Negative margin-top on html and body tags has no effect

Tags: html, css, document-body

I'm trying to remove the vertical scrolling from a page when a dialogue is opened, its a jQuery UI model dialogue as it happens but I don't think that's relevant.

What I'm doing is this:

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$("html, body").css({ "overflow-y": "hidden", "margin-top": (0-scrollTop) + "px" });
```

Which works out what the scroll position of the page is, and then sets it as a negative margin from the top of the page, at the same time as hiding the vertical content that's outside of the scroll area.

This code correctly writes the negative margin as an in-line style to both the html and body tags:

```
<html style="margin-top: -420px; overflow-y: scroll;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body style="margin-top: -420px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    </body>
</html>
```

However it has no effect on the content of the page, its still sits nicely flush against the top of the window.

Does anyone know why this is?

**EDIT:**
Based on the comments below I decided to switch the code to adding a positive margin to the page to see what effect that had, assuming it would add a chunk of empty space to the top of my page.

What it actually did was achieve exactly what I was looking for in the first place.

What I have now is:

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$("html, body").css({ "overflow-y": "hidden", "margin-top": (scrollTop) + "px" });
```

And it works, removing the vertical scrollbar and retaining the scroll position.

Can anyone explain why a positive offset is working when logic would suggest that a negative one would be required?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4887420/6595504 I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Becuase the `html` and `body` elements ARE the page...you can't move the page out of the page...it's not logical.